# Tkinter: How to evenly distribute space between 2 buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I am creating an application using Python 3 and Tkinter.
On my start page (located in class StartPage) I wish to have 2 buttons: 'Student' and 'Teacher', each taking up half of my window.

However the button I .grid first always takes up the majority of the window's width. How do I place the buttons so they are side by side and each span half the window width (while still spanning the full window height)?

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class backEnd(tk.Tk): # pass in Tk module of tk

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self) 
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
        self.frames = {} 

        self.frames[StartPage] = StartPage(parent = container, controller = self)
        self.frames[StartPage].grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nesw')
        self.showFrame(StartPage)

    def showFrame(self, pageName):
        frame = self.frames[pageName]
        frame.tkraise()        

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        teacherButton = tk.Button(self, text = 'Teacher')
        teacherButton.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nesw')

        studentButton = tk.Button(self, text = 'Student')
        studentButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'nesw')


app = backEnd() # equivilant of root = Tk (since backEnd() inherits from Tk)
app.state('zoomed') # makes window fullscreen
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to set `weight=1` for column 1 as well.

Comment: Thank you, that's given me exactly what I wanted!